# select items where column NOT IN itemList

Tags: sql, database, algorithm, sybase

QuickExplain :My elementList is [1, 2, 3, 4] and if  3, 4 is not present in table I want 3, 4.

PS. If you use "NOT IN" this returns you values from table But I want only elements from elementList I queried.

Comment: And what isn't working with your query?

Comment: elementlist is a comma seperated value , so I am not getting how /What to select so that i get one of string which does not matchs

Comment: @Salil No I want 3,4  this case

Comment: The downvoting is easy but its really effortful to understand the question ...that too which is badly explained :(

Comment: I see now that your problem is not sql, so I deleted answer :D

Comment: So if your elementList is [1, 2, 3, 4] and 3, 4 is not present in tab you want 3, 4 is it correct?

Comment: @Salil yes I want 3,4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit verbose but solves the purpose cleanly
select * from 
(select 'item1' as items UNION
select 'item2' as items UNION
.
.
.
select 'itemN' as items ) as notFoundItemList where items NOT IN

(
Select  ITEM from table WHERE  AND itemName in 
)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a temporary table:

```
create table #elements (name varchar(50))

insert into #elements (name) values ('1')
insert into #elements (name) values ('2')
insert into #elements (name) values ('3')
insert into #elements (name) values ('4')

select name
from #elements
where name not in (select col1 from tab);

drop table #elements
```

Comment: Indeed the answer you mentioned is correct but I did not mention is I am calling this within a stored procedure and doing this exposes the tempo table with all other sessions. Another issue then will need create temp table permissions on prod environment. Request to suggest alternative solution\

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the reverse whatever you are doing. If you want only elements from element list then try this

```
select elements from elementList where col1 not in (select col1 from table)
```

Comment: I need items from the passed list that does not match the records , reiterating ... need items from the passed list not from the table .